# read different tabs from csv in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I want to read different tabs from a single csv file. Can anybody help how can I do that ? 
I have multiple req for which I 'm maintaining 4-5 csv files. I'm targeting that I maintain single csv with multiple sheet in a single csv file.

Answer (score 0):

There are no multiple "sheets" in the CSV file as it's plain text. You can have "sheets" in an [Excel file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats), however JMeter doesn't really supports working with Excel files  unless you add [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) library and write custom code using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) to fetch the data from Excel binary files.

If you really want to go into this direction - check out [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test) article for the idea and example implementation.